# Static URL that always links to the latest Go binaries?

Tags: go, download, version, go-toolchain

I am writing some build scripts for packaging some software for a Linux distribution. Inconveniently, this software requires a very recent Go version that's not available in the distribution's repositories. Therefore, I have resorted to directly downloading the built binaries from the official site (https://go.dev/dl/) in the build scripts.

This works alright for now since the URL format is fixed and predictable (`https://go.dev/dl/go$VERSION.$OS-$ARCH.tar.gz`), but it's just mildly irritating that I have to manually update the URL to the Go binaries whenever there is a new version of Go. It gets annoying quickly since I actually have quite a few packages that do things this way.

So I would really love it if there is a static URL that always links to the latest Go binaries, something like `https://go.dev/dl/latest/go.$OS-$ARCH.tar.gz`, but I did not manage to find anything on the official site, nor did a Google search turn up anything.

So does anyone know of such a URL? Preferably one that's officially offered by Golang, but I'll happily use a reasonably-reputable third-party source as well. Thanks.